# "Procfile" template is not found even when file exists

Tags: python, jinja2, erpnext, frappe

I am installing frappe bench by mean of a python script they created but in one of the steps, I am getting this error:

```
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: Procfile
```

By searching the disk, I have found "Procfile" in these folders:

```
/home/frappe/.bench/bench/config/templates/Procfile
/tmp/.bench/bench/config/templates/Procfile
```

I tried by copying that file into the folder where I run the python script, and even, I have copied the file into frappe-bench folder, but nothing helped.

Any hint, please?

Answer (score 0):

you're facing this problem because you've installed the bench using(Editable repo)

    `sudo pip install -e ./bench`

Just remove the -e argument and try to install using

    `sudo pip install ./bench`